# Connecting to MySQL via SSH with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

Is it possible to connect to a MySQL database, on remote server, via SSH using PHP that is installed on my local computer?

I am a bit confused on this subject.  My shared hosting provider suggests I use programs like MySQL Query Browser and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.

I have done some research on SSH at php.net (as well as other places) but their manual on the subject is not very helpful.

Comment: You realize that running queries over a SSH tunnel (AKA VPN connection) will impact the speed that queries are sent to MySQL, and how fast they are returned to the webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'll need to set up a SSH tunnel, and connect via TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to setup a tunnel as mentioned above, you can alternatively execute commands yourself over an open socket.  Look into fsockopen.

Comment: If fsockopen() were to work then a direct connection could just be made instead.